# unit test for redux toolkit prepare callback function

Tags: redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit

My code

```
addTodo: {
  reducer: (state: State, action: { payload: Record<string, string>; type: string }) => {
    state.todoMessage = action.payload.todoMessage;
    state.id = action.payload.id;
    state.completed = action.payload.completed;
  },
  prepare: (todoMessage: string) => {
    return {
      payload: { message: todoMessage, id: uuid(), completed: false }
    };
  }
},
```

and my unit test:

```
const action = {
  type: addTodo.type,
  payload: {
    message: 'buy milk',
    id: 'id',
    completed: false,
  },
};
const state = productDetailsReducer(reducerState, action);
expect(state.todoMessage).toEqual('buy milk');
expect(state.id).toEqual('id');
expect(state.completed).toBeFalsy();
```

my question is that istanbul shows `prepare` function is not covered.
Any idea how to cover it? thanks in advance

Tried to search the redux toolkit document, cannot find anything around it

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `addTodo` action in the unit test so you get coverage over its code. Mock `uuid` to return determinant id value.

Example:

```js
// I'm assuming uuid npm package here, tweak for your specific use case
jest.mock('uuid', () => ({
  v4: jest.fn(() => '12345'),
}));

...

describe("todo slice", () => {
  ...

  it("should add todo", () => {
    const action = addTodo("buy milk");

    const state = productDetailsReducer(reducerState, action);

    expect(state).toEqual({
      todoMessage: "buy milk",
      id: "12345",
      completed: false,
    });
  });

  ...
});
```